# Non-parallel Spaceplane staging?

Tags: stages, spaceplane

The NZ/Netherlands aerospace company Dawn Aerospace is developing it's research scale vehicle, the Mk II:
https://www.dawnaerospace.com/spacelaunch
They haven't detailed their staging system for the second stage yet, but it made me wonder: What forms of Spaceplane second-stage staging configs have been considered.
Please include examples if possible.

Comment: This project seems to be 100% aiming at space tourism so I don't think the payload and upper stage is a given any consideration yet.

Comment: Uh, nope. They aren't even thinking of manned transport.
Not sure what you thought the link was...
They are aiming at small-sat and leo in the long term, and suborbital science in the short term

Comment: The X-37B (uncrewed!) spaceplane is carried to space inside the payload fairing of an Atlas V or Falcon 9 rocket (both rockets have been used). China probably has a similar spaceplane that has been launched atop a Long March 2F rocket, although not much is actually known about it. The Sierra Space Dream Chaser is planned to be launched atop a Vulcan Centaur.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some UK-centric designs:

- Parallel - MUSTARD <sup>[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BAC_Mustard)</sup>
- Piggy back - Interim HOTOL, Space Cab<sup>[b](https://bristolspaceplanes.com/projects/spacecab/)</sup>, AFRL SABRE concept 2<sup>[Y](https://www.thedrive.com/the-war-zone/5380/air-force-eyes-air-breathing-rocket-plane-mothership)</sup>
- Underslung - Orbital Access<sup>[iii](https://pbs.twimg.com/media/Dvqh9OjWoAAMzXf?format=jpg&name=medium)</sup>
- Underwing - Virgin Galactic<sup>[*](https://i.guim.co.uk/img/media/e5a0743a03a96b984ec8f1dc3a72c20f4edeebf7/51_0_2350_1410/master/2350.jpg?width=620&dpr=1&s=none)</sup>
- Payload bay - CNES SABRE TSTO concept 1<sup>[19](https://www.eucass.eu/index.php/component/docindexer/?task=download&id=5791)</sup>
- Bomb bay - AFRL SABRE TSTO concept 1<sup>[Y](https://www.thedrive.com/the-war-zone/5380/air-force-eyes-air-breathing-rocket-plane-mothership)</sup>
- nose cone - CNES SABRE TSTO concept 2<sup>[19](https://www.eucass.eu/index.php/component/docindexer/?task=download&id=5791)</sup>

Comment: @BlueSkinandGlowingRedEyes I think many of these might be on Aeronautix?